# Sync office 365 calendar with SharePoint online calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-calendar

Does anyone have any ideas how to sync office 365 calendar with a sharepoint online calendar?

I have tried overlaying and it doesn't work but need a work around or some way to do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB method to achieve your request.

As a workaround, I recommend you manage office 365 calendar using outlook client.

Comment: Unfortunately all the users use the calendar on their mobiles, so not really possible.